# My exploit does not overwrite EIP, why?

Tags: exploit-development

I am try to write my first exploit, that will exploit the `pinfo` program.

I install the program via `apt-get` them i crash him with:

```
neo@matrix:~$ pinfo -m `python -c 'print "A"*50064+"DCBA"'`

Przemek's Info Viewer v0.6.9
Looking for man page...

*** buffer overflow detected ***: 

pinfo terminated
```

But, don't matter how many 'A' characters i put on the string, EIP isn't  overwriten:

```
neo@matrix:~$ gdb -c ./core
.....

(gdb) x/1000x
...

0xbfe78878: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141

0xbfe78888: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
...

(gdb) info registers

eip            0xb77a0c31   0xb77a0c31 <__kernel_vsyscall+9>
```

How can I make the exploit overwrite the EIP?

Comment: OK, exploit engineering is certainly on-topic here.  Yet, you do not explain your exploit at all!  What do you do to `pinfo` to exploit it?  I'm confident that if I install pinfo from a repository on my machine and run it with the same arguments as you did I will not get the same output as you do.  In other words you're doing a lot more than you're describing in your question.

Comment: Have you checked the EIP address that you're targeting? I've seen cases where the EIP address changes due some reasons.

Comment: Are you sure your version of `pinfo` is actually vulnerable to this exploit?

Comment: Hi people, I am still trying... i will be post the status of my exploitation 's learnings

Comment: Hi guys,

I am trying to learn exploitation. I begin test the exploit 
used to get a  root shell using the pinfo program:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40023/

Firstly:
the pinfo is a vulnerable version because i can smash the stack them and the pinfo -h show  the version:


------------------------
neo@matrix:~/reverse$ /usr/bin/pinfo -h
Przemek's Info Viewer v0.6.9
Usage:
/usr/bin/pinfo [options] [info|manual]

Comment: the problem was the ASLR